# Passing list of values as filtertable content

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, tags

I'm attempting to filter using a list of values with React.

All my "tags" have a "taglevel" to indicate their relevance.

I want it to "cancel out" tags which are the same (ie don't repeat the tag if its' the same).

- I want the first row to show all tag.name with "taglevel" of 1.
- I want the second row to show all tag.name with "taglevel" of 2 or more.

I am unable to show and filter on the value "tags". Possibly it is around line 145 of my codepen where I have made the error.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I've put this together in a codepen.

http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/GqbyWr?editors=1010

Without success, I have now tried the following:

I tried filtering using this using:

```
var LevelFilter = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        if (!this.props.tags) return null;
        return this.props.tags.filter(tag => tag.taglevel === this.props.targetLevel).map(tag => <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>{tag.name}</a>);
    }
});
```

Then trying to get it in my return here:

```
    render: function(){
        ...
        var getUniqueCategories=[];
                PHOTODATA.forEach(function(el){
        if(getUniqueCategories.indexOf(el.tag) === -1 ) getUniqueCategories.push(el.tag);
    })

return (
            <div className="overlay-photogallery">
                <div className="filter-panel"><b>Tags with taglevel 1 only to be displayed</b>
                    {
                        getUniqueCategories.map(function(el,i){
                            var boundClick = titleToSelect.bind(null,el);
                            return <LevelFilter onClick={boundClick} targetLevel={1} tags={el.tag} />
                        })

                    }  
                    <a className="resetBtn" onClick={this.resetFilter}> Reset Filter </a>
                </div>
```

My data looks like this:

```
    "title": "Into the Wild",
    "tag": [
        {
            "name": "Movie",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Adventure",
            "taglevel": 2,
            "id": 30
        },
        {
            "name": "Book",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "info": []
}
```

Comment: Nice formatted question, your details help me to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You have some serious issues with your array manipulation and your React components.

Remember that React advocates a specific top down structure and you should read up on it some more. Each React Component should use props as much as possible and ideally only 1 top-level component should hold state.

---

QUICK ways forward:

1. Pass all the data down and let each level filter make the list unique.
2. Seriously, split up your components and let them depend on props as much as possible.
3. Give variables meaningful names. `el` is not meaningful and in your case refers to PHOTO items in the PHOTODATA array, tags in a PHOTO and then you use `element` to mean something else again. Don't go to over the top, but at least be able to identify what the variable is supposed to do.

I've given in and made a codepen with a much updated structure. The behaviour may not be exactly what you're looking for, but look at the code and how it is organised and how information is shared and passed between components.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXGGLy?editors=1010

---

**UPDATE**
To allow multiple filters two methods should be updated:

```
selectTag: function (tag) {
    this.setState({
      displayedCategories: this.state.displayedCategories.concat([tag])
    });
}

tagFilter: function (photo) {
  return this.props.displayedCategories.length !== 0 && 
    this.props.displayedCategories.every(function(thisTag) {
      return photo.tag.some(function (photoTag) {
        return photoTag.id === thisTag.id &&
          photoTag.taglevel === thisTag.taglevel;
      });
    });
},
```

`selectTag` now appends to the displayedCategories array rather than replacing it.

`tagFilter` now checks that at least one filter has been applied (remove `this.props.displayedCategories.length !== 0` to disable this) so that it doesn't display all by default and then checks that *every* selected filter is present in each `photo`, thus making the components additive.

There are further improvements that could be made, such as to disable a *level* when a filter is applied at that level (one choice per level) or to show a list of applied filters, either through colour on the buttons or a *tag* list above the results.

(codepen updated with these latest changes)

---

Ok, there are a few problems with your codepen.

First, on line 137 you extract the tag array from the object:

```
if(getUniqueCategories.indexOf(el.tag) === -1 ) getUniqueCategories.push(el.tag);
```

Then, on 146 you extract it again:

```
return <LevelFilter onClick={boundClick} targetLevel={1} tags={el.tag} />
```

and again for level 2:

```
return <LevelFilter onClick={boundClick} targetLevel={2} tags={el.tag} />
```

For both of these it should be:

```
return <LevelFilter onClick={boundClick} targetLevel={n} tags={el} />
```

Which then allows another problem to manifest itself, which is that LevelFilter doesn't return a valid React component (an array is not valid).

```
return this.props.tags.filter(tag => tag.taglevel === this.props.targetLevel).map(tag => <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>{tag.name}</a>);
```

should be

```
return (
      <div>            
          {
            this.props.tags
                .filter(tag => tag.taglevel === this.props.targetLevel)
                .map(tag => <a onClick={this.props.onClick}>{tag.name}</a>)
          }
      </div>
    );
```

After these changes you should have a much closer attempt to where you want to be.

There are further issues you will need to look into, things like your boundClick function won't work correctly because you only have a list of tags, not PHOTODATA.

*However*, just a final thought. You might want to break your React components up a little more.

---

For reference, here is the full code listing from the codepen:

```
var PHOTODATA = [{
        "title": "Into the Wild",
        "tag": [
            {
                "name": "Movie",
                "taglevel": 1,
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Adventure",
                "taglevel": 2,
                "id": 30
            },
            {
                "name": "Book",
                "taglevel": 1,
                "id": 2
            }
        ],
        "info": []
    },{
        "title": "Karate Kid",
        "tag": [
            {
                "name": "Movie",
                "taglevel": 1,
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Adventure",
                "taglevel": 2,
                "id": 30
            },
            {
                "name": "Kids",
                "taglevel": 3,
                "id": 4
            }
        ],
        "info": []
    },
        {
        "title": "The Alchemist",
        "tag": [
            {
                "name": "Book",
                "taglevel": 1,
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "Adventure",
                "taglevel": 2,
                "id": 30
            },
            {
                "name": "Classic",
                "taglevel": 2,
                "id": 4
            },
            {
                "name": "Words",
                "taglevel": 4,
                "id": 4
            }
        ],
        "info": []
    }];


var PhotoGallery = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        displayedCategories: []
      };
    },

    selectTag: function (tag) {
        this.setState({
          displayedCategories: this.state.displayedCategories.concat([tag])
        });
    },

    resetFilter: function(){
      this.setState({
        displayedCategories: []
      });
    },

    render: function(){
        var uniqueCategories = PHOTODATA.map(function (photo) {
            return photo.tag; // tag is a list of tags...
        }).reduce(function (uniqueList, someTags) {
            return uniqueList.concat(
              someTags.filter(function (thisTag) {
                return !uniqueList.some(function(uniqueTag) {
                  return uniqueTag.id === thisTag.id && uniqueTag.taglevel === thisTag.taglevel
                });
              })
            );
        }, []);
        return (
            <div className="overlay-photogallery">
                <div className="filter-panel"><b>Tags with taglevel 1 only to be displayed</b>
                    <PhotoGalleryLevel level={1} tags={uniqueCategories} displayedCategories={this.state.displayedCategories} selectTag={this.selectTag} />
                    <a className="resetBtn" onClick={this.resetFilter}> Reset Filter </a>
                </div>
                <div className="filter-panel"><b>Tags with taglevel 2 only to be displayed</b>
                  <PhotoGalleryLevel level={2} tags={uniqueCategories} displayedCategories={this.state.displayedCategories} selectTag={this.selectTag} />
                </div>
                <div className="PhotoGallery">
                    <PhotoDisplay displayedCategories={this.state.displayedCategories} photoData={PHOTODATA} />
                </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
});

var PhotoGalleryLevel = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var filteredTags = this.props.tags.filter(function (tag) {
      return tag.taglevel === this.props.level;
    }.bind(this));
    var disabled = this.props.displayedCategories.some(function (tag) {
      return tag.taglevel === this.props.level;
    }.bind(this));
    return (
      <div>
        {filteredTags.map(function (tag){
          return <PhotoGalleryButton tag={tag} selectTag={this.props.selectTag} disabled={disabled} />;
        }.bind(this))}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var PhotoGalleryButton = React.createClass({
  onClick: function (e) {
    this.props.selectTag(this.props.tag);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <a className={this.props.disabled} onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.tag.name}</a>
    );
  }
});

var PhotoDisplay = React.createClass({
  getPhotoDetails: function (photo) {
    console.log(this.props.displayedCategories, photo);
      return (
        <Photo title={photo.title} name={photo.name} tags={photo.tag} />
      );
  },

  tagFilter: function (photo) {
    return this.props.displayedCategories.length !== 0 && 
      this.props.displayedCategories.every(function(thisTag) {
        return photo.tag.some(function (photoTag) {
          return photoTag.id === thisTag.id &&
            photoTag.taglevel === thisTag.taglevel;
        });
      });
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.photoData.filter(this.tagFilter).map(this.getPhotoDetails)}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Photo =  React.createClass({
    getTagDetail: function (tag){
      return (
        <li>{tag.name} ({tag.taglevel})</li>
      );
    },

  sortTags: function (tagA, tagB) {
    return tagA.taglevel - tagB.taglevel;
  },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="photo-container" data-title={this.props.title} >
                {this.props.title}
                <ul>
                    {this.props.tags.sort(this.sortTags).map(this.getTagDetail)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<PhotoGallery />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

Comment: That seems like a much better approach. Thank you for that. I'm understanding it better. It is functioning with one issue- the filtet/tags should "stack" on top of each other. IE if I choose one filter from level 1, and from level 2- it will only show items relevant to BOTH tags. What is required to do this?

Comment: The key points to look at here are the `selectTag` and the `tagFilter` functions. Currently, `selectTag` always replaces the _displayedCategories_ when it could append (`this.setState({displayedCategories: this.state.displayedCategories.concat([tag])})`) and `tagFilter` does a _some_ operation when it could do _every_, but that may not be quite right. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. It is almost there! I want it to show all tags when no tags are selected. But as a tag is clicked, I want it to **hide** the 'tags' where no results exists for the tiers below. How is this achieved?

Comment: I have created this question in attempt to enable toggling of the filters (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204823/)

Answer (score 1):

With below react component I was able to do what you are looking for,
and here's what i've done in the code,

> i) from the `PHOTODATA` array i have created `taglevel1`, `taglevel2` array
>   one the render method at the begining.
>
> ii) show them in two rows in `showLevel1`, `showLevel2` function.
>
> iii) when the tag item will be click it will call `handleClick` function and filter the data and save it to the `filterData` state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { pluck }    from 'underscore';

class Router extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    filterData: [],
  };
  this.filterArray = [];
    this.PHOTODATA = [{
    "title": "Into the Wild",
    "tag": [
        {
            "name": "Movie",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Adventure",
            "taglevel": 2,
            "id": 30
        },
        {
            "name": "Book",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "info": []
},{
    "title": "Karate Kid",
    "tag": [
        {
            "name": "Movie",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Adventure",
            "taglevel": 2,
            "id": 30
        },
        {
            "name": "Kids",
            "taglevel": 3,
            "id": 4
        }
    ],
    "info": []
},
    {
    "title": "The Alchemist",
    "tag": [
        {
            "name": "Book",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "Adventure",
            "taglevel": 2,
            "id": 30
        },
        {
            "name": "Classic",
            "taglevel": 2,
            "id": 4
        },
        {
            "name": "Words",
            "taglevel": 4,
            "id": 4
        }
    ],
        "info": []
}];
}
handleClick(item) {
const findItem = this.filterArray.indexOf(item);
if (findItem === -1) {
    this.filterArray.push(item);
} else {
  this.filterArray.pop(item);
}
const filterData = [];
if(this.filterArray.length) {
    this.PHOTODATA.map((item) => {
      const data = pluck(item.tag, 'name');
      let count = 0;
      // console.log(data);
      this.filterArray.map((filterItem) => {
        const find = data.indexOf(filterItem);
        if(find !== -1) {
          count++;
        }
        });
        if(count === this.filterArray.length) {
            filterData.push(item);
        }
    });
 }
 console.log(this.filterArray);
 this.setState({ filterData });
}
render() {
const taglevel1 = [];
const taglevel2 = [];
this.PHOTODATA.map((item) => {
        item.tag.map((tagItem) => {
            if(tagItem.taglevel === 1) {
                const find = taglevel1.indexOf(tagItem.name);
                if(find === -1) {
                    taglevel1.push(tagItem.name);
                }
            } else {
                const find = taglevel2.indexOf(tagItem.name);
                if(find === -1) {
                    taglevel2.push(tagItem.name);
                }
            }
        });
});
const showLevel1 = (item, index) => {
  return <span onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, item)}> {item} </span>
};
const showLevel2 = (item, index) => {
  return <span onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, item)}> {item} </span>
};
const showData = (item, index) => {
    return <div>{item.title}</div>
};
return (<div>
  <ul>Tag Level 1: {taglevel1.map(showLevel1)}</ul>
  <ul>Tag Level 2: {taglevel2.map(showLevel2)}</ul>
  <div>Movie Title: {this.state.filterData.map(showData)}</div>
</div>);
}}
```

and here you can see how my outputs look like

[image]