# On/off toggle for filtering content React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This React code is filtering variables according to the "tag" which it contains (as seen in the list array).

However, I cannot toggle the filter variables (tags) on/off.

I want to be able to turn certain filters on/off, and have just those filters apply.

How is this achieved?

My entire code is in this codepen (
http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/GqbyWr?editors=1010)

I believe I have to some how add it to the array on line 79 (below), but I have not had success with this

Line 79:

```
selectTag: function (tag) {
    this.setState({
      displayedCategories: this.state.displayedCategories.concat([tag]),
      $push : [newObject]
    });
},
```

My data looks like this:

```
    "title": "Into the Wild",
    "tag": [
        {
            "name": "Movie",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Adventure",
            "taglevel": 2,
            "id": 30
        },
        {
            "name": "Book",
            "taglevel": 1,
            "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "info": []
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to toggle the filters, you will need to check for the existence of the tag in the existing `displayedCategories`, look through the array for the tag, and then either remove  it or add it in.

It is normally my preference to try to be functional so that assignment cannot cause confusion, so I will use a mostly functional style.

---

First to check for the presence of the tag we can use a *filter* operation.

```
var filteredCategories = this.state.displayedCategories
                             .filter(function (existingTag) {
    return existingTag.taglevel !== tag.taglevel ||
           existingTag.id !== tag.id;
});
```

So we now have a list of tags that are filtered to only include those that don't match the passed tag. We can check if the filtered list is the same size as the old list to see if we removed one. Alternatively, we could have filtered the other way around to see if we needed to remove one using `some`.

```
if (filteredCategories.length === this.state.displayedCategories.length){
    // tag wasn't present, add it
} else {
    // tag was present, use filtered list.
}
```

As I said above, I prefer functional, so we can do it slightly differently:

```
var newCategories = filteredCategories.length === this.state.displayedCategories.length ?
    filteredCategories.concat([tag]) :
    filteredCategories;
```

and then we need to set state:

```
this.setState({
    displayedCategories: newCategories,
});
```

---

To combine those together:

```
var filteredCategories = this.state.displayedCategories
                             .filter(function (existingTag) {
    return existingTag.taglevel !== tag.taglevel ||
           existingTag.id !== tag.id;
});

var newCategories = filteredCategories.length === this.state.displayedCategories.length ?
    filteredCategories.concat([tag]) :
    filteredCategories;

this.setState({
    displayedCategories: newCategories,
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I also wanted the tag content to become hidden if no other items applied to it. This is outside the scope of the question, so posted another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221494