# Conditional display of items- React state based content hiding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This page allows content to be 'filtered' by clicking on tags.

However, it shows tags even when items are not available to when the filter above is selected.

I would like this app to "hide" tags (with a 'taglevel' **higher than 1**) when a tag item is clicked.

For example, if I choose a "book", then tag "blockbuster" should be hidden as it is a "taglevel" 2 item which does not apply to "taglevel" 1 book.

My full code is in this CodePen (http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/GqbyWr?editors=1010).

I am getting the tags here (line 79):

```
selectTag: function (tag) {
        this.setState({
          displayedCategories: this.state.displayedCategories.concat([tag]),
        });
        var filteredCategories = this.state.displayedCategories
                             .filter(function (existingTag) {
        return existingTag.taglevel !== tag.taglevel ||
                existingTag.id !== tag.id;
        });
        var newCategories = filteredCategories.length === this.state.displayedCategories.length ?
        filteredCategories.concat([tag]) :
        filteredCategories;
        this.setState({
            displayedCategories: newCategories,
        });
```

I am calling the buttons (tag/filters) to return here (line 133):

```
var PhotoGalleryButton = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return this.state = {
      isClicked: false
    }
  },
  onClick: function (e) {
    this.setState({
      isClicked: !this.state.isClicked
    })
    this.props.selectTag(this.props.tag);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <a className={this.state.isClicked ? 'filter-panel-1' : ''} onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.tag.name}</a>
    );
  }
});
```

Sample data:

```
        "title": "Karate Kid",
        "tag": [
            {
                "name": "Movie",
                "taglevel": 1,
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Blockbuster",
                "taglevel": 2,
                "id": 29,
            },
            {
                "name": "Kids",
                "taglevel": 3,
                "id": 4
            }
        ],
        "info": []
```

Comment: Why do you set the state twice in your selectTag function?

Comment: I was trying to find a way to apply some kind of UX indicator of when I clicked/toggled the filter. So it applies a CSS change to indicate the value (filter) is on. If there is a better way to do this, please do share